Importing an stl into BambuStudio shows geometry, but in Blender, there is nothing
I looked into this issue and it doesn't seem to be quite the same as what I'm experiencing. I'm playing around with some models to get them ready to print, and three of them are all messed up when I import them into BambuStudio. With this in mind, I just want to correct the models in Blender, but when I import any of them into Blender, I get no geometry to show up. I followed the suggestions I could find online (Pressing ., zooming in and out, scaling differently, etc...) and still am not seeing it. Any ideas for where I can go from here?
In the first picture, you can also see that I can still see geometry from a different model, but the one I'm working with: "watcher2_SubTool1.stl," just doesn't show up. I also notice that the dimensions are 0, and reset to such no matter what I set them to. I scaled it up a ridiculous amount in the screencap to see if that does anything, but I also tried scaling down and still nothing happened.
I also have a second screencap from Bambu, which shows the collection of models, with the one I was importing into Blender specifically selected, where you can see that it's messed up, but that the geometry is still present.
